# Access Soundcloud Charts with API

Tags: soundcloud

Is there an way to access the new charts https://soundcloud.com/charts/top (top 50) with the soundcloud api? Or is there an other way?

Maybe with an crawl with php or something?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To found parameters that you can use with HTTP API Request, you can do this:

- Go to "https://soundcloud.com/charts/" and open Console (F12 on Chrome).
- Go inside Network Tab of Console and Refresh page (F5).
- Clear Console.

Now for example if you want know parameters for retrive "TOP 50 - Dance & EDM":

- Change values inside the filter box
- Check in the console, the request that start with: "charts?kind="
- Search inside this url the parameters.

---

Some example:

TOP | Dance & EDM

https ://api-v2.soundcloud.com/charts?kind=**top**&genre=**soundcloud**%3A**generes**%3A**danceedm**&client_id=...

TOP | Deep House

https ://api-v2.soundcloud.com/charts?kind=**top**&genre=**soundcloud**%3A**genres**%3A**deephouse**&client_id=...

New & Hot

Country
https ://api-v2.soundcloud.com/charts?kind=**trending**&genre=**soundcloud**%3A**genres**%3A**country**&client_id=...

---

***All Parameters:***

kind:

- top      <- Top 50
- trending <- New & Hot

genre:

- soundcloud:genres:all-music
- soundcloud:genres:all-audio
- soundcloud:genres:alternativerock
- soundcloud:genres:ambient
- soundcloud:genres:classical
- soundcloud:genres:country
- soundcloud:genres:danceedm
- soundcloud:genres:dancehall
- soundcloud:genres:deephouse
- soundcloud:genres:disco
- soundcloud:genres:drumbass
- soundcloud:genres:dubstep
- soundcloud:genres:electronic
- soundcloud:genres:folksingersongwriter
- soundcloud:genres:hiphoprap
- soundcloud:genres:house
- soundcloud:genres:indie
- soundcloud:genres:jazzblues
- soundcloud:genres:latin
- soundcloud:genres:metal
- soundcloud:genres:piano
- soundcloud:genres:pop
- soundcloud:genres:rbsoul
- soundcloud:genres:reggae
- soundcloud:genres:reggaeton
- soundcloud:genres:rock
- soundcloud:genres:soundtrack
- soundcloud:genres:techno
- soundcloud:genres:trance
- soundcloud:genres:trap
- soundcloud:genres:triphop
- soundcloud:genres:world
- soundcloud:genres:audiobooks
- soundcloud:genres:business
- soundcloud:genres:comedy
- soundcloud:genres:entertainment
- soundcloud:genres:learning
- soundcloud:genres:newspolitics
- soundcloud:genres:religionspirituality
- soundcloud:genres:science
- soundcloud:genres:sports
- soundcloud:genres:storytelling
- soundcloud:genres:technology

---

Example in php to get a json response of TOP50 - Country:

URL:
https ://api-v2.soundcloud.com/charts?kind=**top**&genre=**soundcloud**%3A**genres**%3A**country**&client_id=**XXXXXXXXXXX**&limit=**10**&linked_partitioning=**1**

**URL Parameters:**

Kind: Top 
Genre: soundcloud:genres:country 
client_id: XXXXXXXXXXX 
limit: 10 
linked_partitioning: 1

**limit:** how many songs you want to receive in response.
**linked_partitioning:** page number, according to the limit.

e.g. linked_partitioning with Limit = 10:

- 1 get song from 0 to 9
- 2 get song from 10 to 19
- ...

e.g. linked_partitioning with Limit = 20:

- 1 get song from 0 to 19
- 2 get song from 20 to 39
- ...

Now that you have URL, if you want retrive JSON response with PHP 
you have to write for example:

```
<?php 
    $url = "https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/charts?kind=top&genre=soundcloud%3Agenres%3Acountry&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&limit=10&linked_partitioning=1";
    // Get JSON Response
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    // Decode response to array
    $objectJSON = json_decode($json, true);
```

Example Json Response:

```
{
    "genre":"soundcloud:genres:country",
    "kind":"top",
    "last_updated":"2016-03-24T09:50:02Z",
    "collection":[
        {
            "track":{
                "commentable":true,
                "comment_count":211,
                "downloadable":true,
                "download_count":80,
                "duration":251060,
                .
                .
                .
                "kind":"track",
                .
                .
                .
                .
                "license":"all-rights-reserved",
                "streamable":true,
                "title":"Award winning Falling Star",
                "uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/245170733",
                .                
                .
                .
                "country_code":"US"
            }
            "score":1093171.0
        },
        {
            ...
        },
        OTHER TRACKS HERE...
    ],
    "query_urn":"soundcloud:charts:bc9b903f2cee44e7bca955bc2fc4601d",
    "next_href":"https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/charts?genre=soundcloud%3Agenres%3Acountry&query_urn=soundcloud%3Acharts%3Abc9b903f2cee44e7bca955bc2fc4601d&offset=20&kind=top&limit=20"
    }
}
```

If you want read JSON content of response:

```
    // Read Json taking for example Name, Title and SoundCloud URI of song.
    foreach ($objectJSON["collection"] as $key => $value) {
        echo 'user: ' . $value['track']['user']['full_name'] . "<br/>";
        echo 'title: ' . $value['track']['title'] . "<br/>";
        echo 'url: ' . $value['track']['uri'] . "<br/><br/>";
    } 
    echo $response;
?>
```

Result of this PHP:

```
user: ...
title: ...
url: ...

user: ...
title: ...
url: ...

...
```

[Example of this code](http://steebono.com/TOP50Country.php)

---

I hope I have helped you and sorry for my english.

EDIT:

I think that SoundCloud has changed the way to get the next page.
Now you need to change the "offset" param.

Like this:

```
Page 1: ....&limit=20&offset=0
Page 2: ....&limit=20&offset=20
Page 3: ....&limit=20&offset=40
```

---

#### ANSWER FOR @VietHung QUESTION.


Q: Can you explore system playlists? 
(Eg: soundcloud:system-playlists charts-top:all-music)

To find system playlist, I have used *Charles Web Debugging Proxy*.
The idea is to sniff network package sent by SoundClound App from iOS device (in my case).

After that you configure Charles to sniff SSL packages correctly, you can use you pc as proxy for your smartphone.
(You must install Charles cert on Windows and on iOS device to sniff SSL packages correctly, for more information search on google).

Now, open SoundCloud App and click on every playlists (TOP, NEWS) inside the app.
Below a screenshot (Quality powered by paint, sorry ahah):
[image: SoundCloud APP]

Now inside Charles we can see something like this:

[image: Charles_Request_Soundcloud]

I set the focus only on the SoundCloud host for better reading of incoming packages.
Charles is smart and puts all similar requests into a subfolder, in our case we have to look at all the requests within 'system-playlist'.

Now from all requests you can retrieve all system playlists values.

I have not listed all playlist song because currently I do not have much time.
As soon as I can, I edit this post with the complete list of possible system playlists vales.

Comment: You saved my day.. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Bye

Comment: You explain it very beautifully, learn many new thing from this answer

Comment: I need your help. I want to display soundcloud top 50 song country wise. can you help me in this..

Comment: Can you provide the url for fetching songs by genre? The earlier one is not working now.

Comment: This work perfectly!
Try this: https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/charts?kind=top&genre=soundcloud%3Agenres%3Acountry&client_id=02gUJC0hH2ct1EGOcYXQIzRFU91c72Ea&limit=10&linked_partitioning=1

Comment: @SteeBono Thanks. You have saved me so much time. But one problem is occurring. While i sent data like (linked_partitioning=1& Limit = 10) or (linked_partitioning=2& Limit = 10) result is same.

Comment: @SteeBono thank you for replay. I have already solved that problem and correct your answer also. Check it and accept that edit. so another developer will not confuse.

Comment: @PramodTapaniya Done! Thanks.

Comment: Can you explore system playlists? Example: soundcloud:system-playlists charts-top:all-music. Soundcloud server will detect request's IP, and return different data with different IP

Comment: @VietHung what do you mean with 'system playlist'?

Comment: @SteeBono like this: https://api-mobile.soundcloud.com/system-playlists/soundcloud:system-playlists:charts-top:all-music (include client_id of official soundcloud app to get result)

Comment: @SteeBono I would like to make an app to explore all TOP 50 of all countries. But SoundCloud api detected IP's client and return data based on it. Do you have any idea? :(((

Comment: @VietHung Are you sure? Maybe is based on users preferences?  I mean that maybe I listen to certain type of songs, so the playlist goes according to my taste. Or maybe depends if user is logged in..  These are just my suppositions.

Comment: @VietHung Maybe it’s based on country? I don’t know, you can create a WebService to make requests to soundcloud mobile api, host it on ISS and then from your app/website, request data to your WebService, in this way your WebService has always the same IP, and every client that request playlist receive the same data. (Maybe a possible solution?)

Comment: @SteeBono Yes, like this: https://static.mainstreammedia.io/soundcloud/US But my server takes 12h for requesting of all countries. Too long

Comment: @SteeBono Amazing solution. Do you know if there's a way to retrieve previous top 50? The API returns just the most recent top 50, is there a way (for example) to get the top 50 of a month ago?

Comment: @MattiaSurricchio Hi, I don't think it's possible.
Can you see the history of the 'top 50' on the soundcloud website?

Comment: @SteeBono Unfortunately you can't. The only exposed one is the very last chart

Comment: @MattiaSurricchio Since these APIs are not public, we cannot know if there is an API that returns the history. Especially if there isn't this feature on the SoundCloud website.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/charts?kind=top&genre=soundcloud%3Agenres%3Aall-music&client_id=02gUJC0hH2ct1EGOcYXQIzRFU91c72Ea&limit=20&offset=0
```

Just change the params according to your client id, etc.

Comment: Where can i get the list of genres for the `genre` param? ie. `soundcloud:genres:country`(doesnt work)

Comment: @Andy That seems to literally be an example API request, not a link to an example program.  It's not a great answer, but by our low standards, it is an answer.

Comment: This seems to be a private/undocumented API.  Care to explain how you found this/what the parameters are?