# Soundcloud API: How to get soundcloud top chart playlist id?

Tags: rest, api, soundcloud, playlist

Does soundcloud have or expose the playlist ID of it's top charts via its http api?

Example playlist:

1. https://soundcloud.com/charts/top
2. https://soundcloud.com/charts/top?genre=country

If yes, how can I find out the playlist ID?

I intent to use the playlist ID to make api call to return me the list of tracks as json data

Example: $ curl "http://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/PLAYLIST_ID?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID"

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688367/access-soundcloud-charts-with-api

Comment: That's sort of helpful but it's a pity there's no direct "playlist_id" one can use to make an api call :-(